# Angular js: an arrray from one file to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I am new to Angular js.I have included two files and both the files works fine separately - i can add names to the array and delete or update them, but the idea is to be able to get the array from one file and get it to the other dynamically. Because when i swich views the arrays are still stored (until a refresh)
How can i connect the two .js files because the two modules are in two separate files and the two views make both array with string names. What i want is basically call a function(getallDepartments) from the employee module and get the array of names of departments from the department module. And i know i cant use like require or include but i don't need to save the data to a database so what is the best other approach here? So i have this code:

p.s. I've tried dependency inject the department factory in the employee module but since it doesn't know from where that factory comes from this is useless - and i can't reference the script inside another script...

employees.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.employees', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/employees', {
    templateUrl: 'employees/employees.html',
    controller: 'View2Ctrl',
    controllerAs:"View2"
  });
}])


.factory('EmployeeService', function()
{
    var employees = [];

return {
    deleteEmployee: function(employee) {
        var index  = employees.indexOf(employee);
        if(index > -1)
        {
            employees.splice(index,1);
        }
    },
    addEmployee: function(employee) {
        employees.push(employee);
    },
    getallEmployee: function()
    {
        return employees;
    },
    getallDepartment: function()
    {
        console.log("fdfs");
        //console.log(DepartmentService.getallDepartments())
        return DepartmentService.getallDepartments();
    },
    updateEmployee: function(employee,newname) {
        var index  = employees.indexOf(employee);
        if(index > -1)
        {
            employees[index] = newname;     
        }
    }
} 
})


.controller('View2Ctrl', function(EmployeeService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.employees = EmployeeService.getallEmployee();

    vm.addEmployee = function(employee) {
        EmployeeService.addEmployee(employee);
    }

    vm.deleteEmployee = function(employee) {
        EmployeeService.deleteEmployee(employee);
    }

    vm.selectEmployee = function(employee) {
        vm.employeeSelected = true;
        vm.updateEmployeeName = employee;
    }

    vm.updateEmployee = function(employee) {
        EmployeeService.updateEmployee(vm.employee,vm.updateEmployeeName);
    }

    //vm.Check = function()
    //{
    //  EmployeeService.getallDepartment();
    //} 
});





'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.departments', ['ngRoute'])


.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/departments', {
    templateUrl: 'departments/departments.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl',
    controllerAs: "View1"

  });
 }])


.factory('DepartmentService', function()
{
    var departments = [];

return {
    deleteDepartment: function(department) {
        var index  = departments.indexOf(department);
        if(index > -1)
        {
            departments.splice(index,1);
        }
    },
    addDepartment: function(department) {
        departments.push(department);
    },
    getallDepartments: function()
    {
        return departments;
    },
    updateDepartment: function(department,newname) {
        var index  = departments.indexOf(department);
        if(index > -1)
        {
            departments[index] = newname;   
        }
    }
} 
})

.controller('View1Ctrl', function(DepartmentService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.departments = DepartmentService.getallDepartments();

    vm.addDepartment = function(department) {
        DepartmentService.addDepartment(department);
    }

    vm.deleteDepartment = function(department) {
        DepartmentService.deleteDepartment(department);
    }

    vm.selectDepartment = function(department) {
        vm.departmentSelected = true;
        vm.updateDepartmentName = department;
    }

    vm.updateDepartment = function(department) {
        DepartmentService.updateDepartment(vm.department,vm.updateDepartmentName);
    }
});
```

and this is the employees.html

```
<table
<p></p>
<h1>Update</h1>
<input ng-model="View2.updateEmployeeName" ng-disabled="!View2.employeeSelected">
<button ng-click="View2.updateEmployee(View2.employeeSelected)">UpdateEmployee</button>
<hr>
      <table border="1px" style="width: 200px" ng-repeat="employee in View2.employees">
      <tr>
      <td>{{employee}}</td>
      <td><button ng-click="View2.deleteEmployee(employee)">Delete</button></td>
      <td><button ng-click="View2.selectEmployee(employee)">Update</button></td>
      <td><button ng-click="View2.Check()">Check</button></td>
          </tr> 
      </table>
<hr>
<h1>Create</h1>

<input ng-model="View2.employee">
<button ng-click="View2.addEmployee(View2.employee)">AddEmployee</button>
```

Comment: Don't think of them as in different files. You have various components all  within one app. To share data between components use a service

Comment: yes and i have .factory in both components but now how can i reach one factory from one component to the other ?

Answer (score 0):

Factories can be used in different modules, but they **don't** need to be declared as dependencies of those modules (like you're doing with 'ngRoute').

You're currently injecting the department service in the department controller.

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', function(DepartmentService) {
```

You can do the same in the employee controller, and then copy over the line you need from your department controller:

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', function(EmployeeService, DepartmentService) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.employees = EmployeeService.getallEmployee();
    vm.departments = DepartmentService.getallDepartments();

    ...
```

Except it won't work out of the box if they're in different files. In that case, you need to use the $inject provider. I suggest you refactor your .controller declaration to make the second argument into a named function:

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', View2Ctrl)

function View2Ctrl(EmployeeService, DepartmentService) {
    ...
}
```

And then you can add this line (Outside the View2Ctrl function, anywhere in the same file):

```
View2Ctrl.$inject = ['EmployeeService', 'DepartmentService']
```

The order in which you list the services to inject need to be the same both in the function arguments and in the array of strings you're defining View2Ctrl.$inject as.

The other way of doing this would be to wrap your controller function in square brackets, (effectively declaring an array), and listing your services as strings in that array:

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', ['EmployeeService', 'DepartmentService', function(EmployeeService, DepartmentService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.employees = EmployeeService.getallEmployee();
    vm.departments = DepartmentService.getallDepartments();

    ...

}]);
```

In both cases, you'll be able to use every method of both factories inside your controller.

Comment: The final way was exactly what i was asking for. Thanks a lot, cheers mate! :)